# Fix "DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions"

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am getting the following Error:

```
DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
```

When ever i try to execute a command

-code here- (removed for private reasons)

## Edit

This is after a year and I have decided to remove the code here since it contained some private stuff of my discord bot (now closed)

And I didn't know how to code at that time so the code here was bad

The most general fix would be to check permission on the guild (inside the code) when  doing any action in it (as said in the answer)
and return a error or do abort the action if no permission was given to the bot.

If The bot is in your guild and you want to make sure it works, check the bots roles and permission inside your guild

Comment: Could you give the full error? Normaly, it should tell you at which line an error occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you have to reduce amount of listeners (that means `client.on`, `client.once`), it incredibly slows down the API, but also is simply messy and can often end up with an error. Use each listener **once**.

If you have missing permission error, then it means your bot is missing a permission to perform an action, be sure to check for permissions needed to perform an action before actually performing it. You can do that with ([docs](https://v12.discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions.html#checking-member-permissions)):

```js
message.guild.me.hasPermission('SOME_PERMISSION');
```

### Update

As of Discord.js v13 you have to use ([docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=has)):

```
message.guild.me.permissions.has(Permission.SOME_PERMISSION);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply,ill see into it and if I can find anything ill mark this as the answer  the issue is this is happening at the startup so whats would be the startup issue that can cause this